# Reference column with assigned variable in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to convert a column in my data table from factor to numeric values, but the catch is I am using a "dictionary" (a list) so I want to be able to refer to the column variable via the "dictionary":

```r
#my "dictionary"
outcomes <- list("heart attack"="Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Attack",
               "heart failure"="Number of Patients - Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Heart Failure",
               "pneumonia"="Number of Patients - Hospital 30-Day Death (Mortality) Rates from Pneumonia")
#named variable
outcome <- outcomes[["heart attack"]]

#conversion function
as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}

#convert my data table column from factor to numeric
DT[, outcome := as.numeric.factor(outcome)]
```

`DT[, outcome := as.numeric.factor(outcome)]` is ideally what I want to do, but I know I can't just stick a named variable `outcome` in there and hope data table will know I am referring to the column that has the value of `outcome`. Sorry I'm quite new to data table and I am a bit confused about how to deal with named variables in general when referencing columns.

Comment: It should be better if you share also an extract of your data (anonymized). Anyway you may try `mutate_at` from `tidyverse` package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)
Your_df_mod <- Your_df %>% 
    mutate_at(.vars=outcome,.funs=funs(as.numeric(.)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(mtcars)[, mpg := as.factor(mpg)]
class(DT$mpg)
# [1] "factor"

as.numeric.factor <- function(x) {as.numeric(levels(x))[x]}
outcome <- "mpg"
# Reference column by assigned variable
DT[, (outcome) := as.numeric.factor(get(outcome))]
class(DT$mpg)
# [1] "numeric"
```